# Calculating the distance between 2 points in c#

Tags: c#, latitude-longitude

I am trying to sort out a method to calculate the distance between 2 points in c#.

This is the code I have been trying though I fear the answer I get is not correct.

```
static void Main()
    {
        //postcode australia 2600 -> 3000
        float latA = -31.997976f;
        float longA = 115.762877f;
        float latB = -31.99212f;
        float longB = 115.763228f;
        decimal distance = (DistanceBetween(latA, latB, longA, longB));
        Console.WriteLine("Distance is" + distance);
        Console.ReadLine();
    }

    static decimal DistanceBetween(float latA, float longA, float latB, float longB)
    {
        var RadianLatA = Math.PI * latA / 180;
        var RadianLatb = Math.PI * latB / 180;
        var RadianLongA = Math.PI * longA / 180;
        var RadianLongB = Math.PI * longB / 180;

        double theDistance = (Math.Sin(RadianLatA)) *
                Math.Sin(RadianLatb) +
                Math.Cos(RadianLatA) *
                Math.Cos(RadianLatb) *
                Math.Cos(RadianLongA - RadianLongB);

        return Convert.ToDecimal(((Math.Acos(theDistance) * (180.0 / Math.PI)))) * 69.09M * 1.6093M;
    }
```

this was adapted from a response found on this site here
[Distance between addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999187/distance-between-addresses)

Any thoughts on what is going wrong/

Thanks
Ryan

Comment: http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html This site always helped me out with calculating distances between two points.

Comment: Thanks, good link. I am putting this in an asp.net application to calculate the distances between postcodes so i need to get this code right!

Comment: My first guess will be a sign issue in your trignometric conversions. Pull up wolframalpha or a calculator, step through the code and see the results for each of your ```Math.Sin``` (or other trig functions) and see if the results match.
Converting from degrees to radians must also take account for sign when being used in trig functions

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The class I usually use is [GeoCoordinate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

```
double latA = -31.997976f;
double longA = 115.762877f;
double latB = -31.99212f;
double longB = 115.763228f;

var locA = new GeoCoordinate(latA, longA);
var locB = new GeoCoordinate(latB, longB);
double distance = locA.GetDistanceTo(locB ); // metres
```

Comment: I tried this yesterday but if I ever wrote in "using System.Device.Location" it came up with an error. Do i have to add in this class manualy some how?

Comment: You need to add a project reference to the System.Device dll, it's not included by default

Comment: Thankyou so much. I will do this now :)

Comment: 100% working and integrated into the rest of my code. I cannot explain to you how much you have helped me!!!

Comment: @user1672867 no worries. Can you please accept the answer you used in the end?

Answer (score 6):

```
double lat1 = {};
double lat2 = {};
double lon1 = {};
double lon2 = {};

var R = 6376.5000; //Km
lat1 = lat1.ToRad();
lat2 = lat2.ToRad();
lon1 = lon1.ToRad();
lon2 = lon2.ToRad();
var dLat = lat2 - lat1;
var dLon = lon2 - lon1;
var a = Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dLat / 2), 2) + (Math.Pow(Math.Sin(dLon / 2), 2) * Math.Cos(lat1) * Math.Cos(lat2));
var c = 2 * Math.Atan2(Math.Sqrt(a), Math.Sqrt(1 - a));
var distance = R * c;

public double ToRad(this double degs) {
    return degs * (Math.PI/180.0);
}
```

Input expects doubles.

This is the haversine formula, it's used to calculate the distances on our globe between two points. This is the distance in a straight line, if you need the distance on a path you will have to find all points on that path and then calculate the distances between each two points and then take the sum of that.

Comment: Thanks I am giving this a go now :)

Comment: Since you are a new user, don't forget to upvote/mark as an answer it this answer was helpfull.

Comment: It suggests i need 15 reputation before i can perform said action :S

Comment: While this approach is perfectly valid (assuming the formula is correct) I prefer to use a built in method where possible as it's used by users across the world - less chance of an error!

Comment: @Liath which built-in methods are you talking about?

Comment: @woutervs I use GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo() myself

Comment: Will look into that next time I need distance data. Thanks that might be usefull.

Comment: Someone upvoted, which led me to revisiting my old code and noticing an error in it. It's updated now, if you decompile GeoCoordinate.GetDistanceTo() you'll find about the same code, but instead of it being in kilometres it's in metres.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [DbGeography](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) for spatial calculation. It has [DbGeography.Distance](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.spatial.dbgeography.distance%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method which is used to calculate the distance between two gps points.

Otherwise, try [Ref: Harversine Formula](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/live/en-US/39e18644-f075-4691-8507-e5e598b4a0f6/calculate-distance-between-2-gps-position?forum=vemapcontroldev) to calculate the distance between two points.

Comment: Not seen that one, I usually use GeoCoordinate - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.device.location.geocoordinate(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Please forgive my stupidity. i tried Geocoordinate but could not get it to work. I am quite new to programming. I am going to try this now. Will I have to define "using System.Data.Spatial" to be able to use that method?

Comment: @user1672867 I think I've got an example somewhere in one of my previous question. I'll try and dig it out - I was just curious of the difference between GeoCoordinate and DBGeography...

Answer (score -6):

Distance Formula: Given the two points (x1, y1) and (x2, y2), the distance between these points is given by the formula:

[image]

use it accordingly

Comment: That would be right on a flat surface, not on a globe :)

Comment: try this link hope it helps ..other  http://www.calculatorsoup.com/calculators/geometry-solids/distance-two-points.php