# How to search Latitude and Longitude based record from SQL Server use Asp.net MVC and C#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server

I want to search all records from my SQL Server database, based on some conditions
like "Near by 5 Km area", "people from my present location" (Male, Female, Both) etc.

The table structure looks like this:

[image: Table structure]

So, how can I do this?

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show your table design and what queries you have written so far.

Comment: @PeterSmith, please see my edited question

Comment: now you are talking :)

Answer (score 2):

Have a read of my StackOverflow answer here:

[Get the nearest longitude and latitude from MSSQL database table?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37326089/391605)

Basically, you can use the SQL Server `geography` type, then use `STDistance`.

This article includes an example, showing exactly how to use it, and also how to use Pythagorus, to calculate the distances even quicker.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll be force to use something like google maps API for c# to count the distance.

Otherwise, maybie you have something like additional "distance from" table, but I don't think so...
In general even if you have some table with columns like Addres, Gender it's still not that easy to perform:
[Distance between addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999187/distance-between-addresses)
Solution from that answer:

```
public decimal calcDistance(decimal latA, decimal longA, decimal latB, decimal longB)
{

    double theDistance = (Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(latA)) *
            Math.Sin(DegreesToRadians(latB)) +
            Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(latA)) *
            Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(latB)) *
            Math.Cos(DegreesToRadians(longA - longB)));

    return Convert.ToDecimal((RadiansToDegrees(Math.Acos(theDistance)))) * 69.09M * 1.6093M;
}
```

Comment: can you share me some links

Comment: here it is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999187/distance-between-addresses