# C# Getting lat and long from Google GeoCoding API

Tags: c#, json, google-maps, google-geocoding-api

In my C# project, I'm trying to get the lat and long location of a building. I used this thread as a base [Distance between addresses](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13999187/distance-between-addresses) and tried to adapt it to get the lat and long of a location. At the moment, the getting the JSON response from the API is fine, it's getting the value I want from the JSON response.

Here is my code at the moment

```
string requesturl = url;
string content = fileGetContents(requesturl);
JObject o = JObject.Parse(content);
user.Latitude = (double)o.SelectToken("results[0].geometry[0].location[0].lat");
user.Longitude = (double)o.SelectToken("results[0].geometry[0].location[0].lng");

protected string fileGetContents(string fileName)
    {
        string sContents = string.Empty;
        string me = string.Empty;
        try
        {
            if (fileName.ToLower().IndexOf("https:") > -1)
            {
                System.Net.WebClient wc = new System.Net.WebClient();
                byte[] response = wc.DownloadData(fileName);
                sContents = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(response);

            }
            else
            {
                System.IO.StreamReader sr = new System.IO.StreamReader(fileName);
                sContents = sr.ReadToEnd();
                sr.Close();
            }
        }
        catch { sContents = "unable to connect to server "; }
        return sContents;
    }
```

Comment: Please update your question to include the value of `content`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like the problem is that you're trying to access geometry and location as if they were lists. Try this:

```
user.Latitude = (double)o.SelectToken("results[0].geometry.location.lat");
user.Longitude = (double)o.SelectToken("results[0].geometry.location.lng");
```